# How to bind IsChecked property of an AppBarToggleButton to the Playing state of MediaElement

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-runtime, mediaelement

I am developing a media player app. I have a AppBarToggleButton ABBPlayPause which when Checked plays media and changes its Icon to Pause. Also i have set `AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"`.

```
< MediaElement AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" x:Name="mediafile"/>

< AppBarToggleButton Label="Play" x:Name="ABBPlayPause" Checked="ABBPlayPause_Checked" Unchecked="ABBPlayPause_Unchecked" Icon="Play"/>
```

Problem: I am unable to bind the IsChecked property of ABBPlayPause to the Click of Play Button in TransportControl of MediaElement nor i can find any property of MediaElement that can identify if the media is playing or not.

```
    private void ABBPlayPause_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediafile.Play();
        ABBPlayPause.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Pause);
        ABBPlayPause.Label = "Pause";
        ABBStop.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void ABBPlayPause_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediafile.Pause();
        ABBPlayPause.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Play);
        ABBPlayPause.Label = "Play";
    }
```

Comment: No..Actually I am not working on it anymore